# How can I make an entry point for my tkinter application?

Tags: python, tkinter, entry-point

I have some code that uses Tkinter and it opens a window and waits for the user to click a button. I want to make an executable with pyinstaller. So I did it using `pyinstaller --onefile sayHi.py`. It worked and I had an executable but when I ran it, it did nothing. I have read it is because I don't have an entry point. So after reading a lot I still can't understand how entry points work.

**How can I make an entry point that will run sayHi.py?**
Here you have my project structure:

```
sayHi/
|
├── scripts/
|   └── sayHi.py
└── setup.py
```

This is the file: sayHi.py. I want it to be executed when clicking on my sayHi.exe:

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk, Button

window = Tk()
window.geometry('700x300')

def sayHi():
    window2 = Tk()
    window2.geometry('300x100')
    label = Label(window2, text="Hi")
    label.pack()

downloadButton = Button(window, text='Press to say hi', command=sayHi)
downloadButton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Here's my other file setup.py which I am really not sure of how it works:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='sayHi',
    version='0.1.0',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'sayHi=sayHi',
        ]
    }
)
```

Please someone explain me how can I make an entry point that will run sayHi.py. Also, now that I have this setup file do I have to run `pyinstaller --onefile sayHi.py` or `pyinstaller --onefile setup.py`. I'm very confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think Python has a concept of entrypoints: scripts are executed from top to bottom. Are you sure the compiled executable did nothing? What happened when you tried to run it? Were there any errors in the console?

Comment: You have misdiagnosed this. I don't know what's wrong, but it's certainly not because you don't have an entry point. When you tell pyinstaller to freeze sayHi.py, that's defining the entry point as sayHi.py.

Comment: Well I read it here: https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/. When I ran it it opened a black window and then closed.

Comment: That black window contained the error message describing what went wrong. Launch your program from the command line so that you can read it.

Comment: @ForceBru: I don't know whether this is the problem on this script, but Python projects can certainly have entry points - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html